Why did the angels fight over Moses’ body if God told Moses he would never enter the promised land? (Deu 3:23)
Please reference Jude 9, Deuteronomy 3:23-26.
Yet Michael the archangel, when contending with the devil and disputing about the body of Moses, dared not bring against him a railing accusation, but said, “The Lord rebuke thee!”
“Get thee up into the top of Pisgah, and lift up thine eyes westward, and northward, and southward, and eastward, and behold it with thine eyes: for thou shalt not go over this Jordan.”

I have seen two separate questions pertaining to this subject matter but not a question tying the two together. Could Moses not go over in life or death (burial)?

My answer is speculative, but I think the reason Jude reported that the devil wanted Moses' body was that it could supposedly be used for evil magical purposes. (Assyrian and Egyptian magic often involved graves and decomposed bodies.) Michael naturally sought to prevent this and to allow Moses' body to remain undisturbed.
Scholars think Jude's reference to the struggle between the devil and Michael is a reference to the incomplete first-century text known as the Assumption of Moses together with background material from the Book of Enoch which speaks in detail of the activity of fallen angels. An introduction published by the US Council of Catholic Bishops states:

Most scholars believe that Jude... quotes two apocryphal Jewish works,
the Assumption of Moses (Jude 9) and the Book of Enoch (Jude 14–15)

In the Assumption of Moses, Joshua asks:

What place shall receive you?  Or what shall be the sign that marks
(your) sepulcher? Or who shall dare to move your body from there as
that of a mere man from place to place?

Because the text is fragmentary, we do not know if Jude drew additional material from the original version. However, one of the main concerns of Jude's short letter is the teaching and activity of fallen angels:

The angels too, who did not keep to their own domain but deserted
their proper dwelling, he has kept in eternal chains, in gloom, for
the judgment of the great day.

This is a reference to the Book of 1 Enoch, which speaks at length of the angels' fall, their fornication with human women, their spreading of forbidden knowledge, and their role of the unfallen archangels in response:
1 Enoch 8-9

Azazel taught men to make swords, and knives, and shields... and bracelets, and ornaments, and the use of
antimony, and the beautifying of the eyelids, and all kinds of costly
stones, and all 2 colouring tinctures. And there arose much
godlessness, and they committed fornication, and they 3 were led
astray, and became corrupt in all their ways. Semjaza taught
enchantments, and root-cuttings, Armaros the resolving of
enchantments, Baraqijal (taught) astrology, Kokabel the
constellations, Ezeqeel the knowledge of the clouds, Araqiel the signs
of the earth, Shamsiel the signs of the sun, and Sariel the course of
the moon. . . 1 And then Michael, Uriel, Raphael, and Gabriel looked
down from heaven and saw much blood being 2 shed upon the earth, and
all lawlessness being wrought upon the earth.

Conclusion: So Jude was apparently aware of the fallen angels' interest in forbidden magical practices. This leads to the idea that the devil would contend with Michael over Moses' holy body for purposes of powerful necromancy. Michael, on the other hand, sought to prevent this outcome.

Verses in Jude deal with wicked people who "defile the flesh, despise dominion, and speak evil of dignities." This, immediately before saying how the archangel, Michael, contended (verbally) with the devil. The devil apparently had made some evil accusation about Moses and/or Moses' body. Yet the archangel did not fall into the trap of responding in like manner to the devil. He would not verbally attack the devil, but simply responded, "May the Lord rebuke thee."
It would appear that it was the devil who wanted a fight, but the archangel would not grant him one. After all, it takes two to have a fight.
Jude then returns to the disgraceful attitudes of the wicked men who were trying to corrupt the Christian congregation. They "speak evil of those things which they know not". But Michael did not use his superior knowledge of Moses and his death to give the devil ground for creating a prolonged debate. Neither should anybody else, especially those who do not know what God did with Moses' undiscovered body.
This means that there is no link to Deuteronomy 3:23 with regard to this question, for God telling Moses he would never enter the Promised Land sheds no light (for us) as to what God did with Moses' body. And even the archangel (who likely did know) knew to keep silence about the matter before that wicked accuser of the brethren. There was no fight over Moses' body. There was only an attempt by that satanic troublemaker to disparage Moses in order to get Michael to sin in his speech. We do well to recall that Jesus said we will be judged for every careless word - Matthew 12:36.

The promised land was a physical location on earth, the land in occupation by the Canaanites and other tribes flowing with milk and honey. This promised land, Moses was not going for reasons known to the Lord, now concerning Moses' eternal destination, which is the true promised land every Christian aspires to inherit, the devil challenged his inheritance of the spiritual promised land by arguing that Moses had sinned by getting angry and taking the glory of the water out of stone miracle at Marah Rephidim, so the devil thought the soul of Moses belonged to him but God could not allow it, why did God do this? Moses did more good than evil, in the Old Testament, judgment worked by way of scales where your good deeds and evil dees are weighed and then the side that overcomes the other determines your fate. Moses performed a lot of signs before the princes of Egypt and the children of Israel, although he sinned by killing the Egyptian and other evil works, God forgave him as it is written
Romans 9:15

For he says to Moses, “I will have mercy on whom I have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I have compassion.”

Jesus had mercy on the thief to the right despite his evil stealing works, he confessed and one day I will see him in heaven and we will discuss a lot in joy and happiness.
